# Access to vue root instance in vuex module action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

According to github accessing the vue root instance is quite easy in actions.

https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1399

I've tested it ant it works. This is my store setup:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    actions: {
        testPieter (context) {
            console.log('this in testpieter', this)
            console.log('vm in testpieter', this._vm)
        }
    },
    modules: {
      userStore,
      notifications,
      safetyDrone
  },
  strict: debug
})
```

Problem is, in the actions in the modules I can't seem to access the vue instance, when i console.log the store from the action:

[image]

when i console.log(this) from the action i just get the exports defined in the module file..

Is there a built-in/elegant way to access the vue root instance?

Comment: In the github link that you provided, there are few workarounds suggested. [pass vue instance to action](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1399#issuecomment-425331925), [attach vue instance to the store when the store is created](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1399#issuecomment-491553564) and few other. Did non of those solve your problem?

Comment: That works for an action in the rootstore, but not for an action in a module.. Seems like another store is passed/used there

Comment: If you pass your vue instance to the action, it should work no matter where the action is. `this.$store.dispatch('myAction', { vm: this });` on the github page. And then you can access it with `myAction(context, { vm })` in your action

Comment: That's true, you are right. IMHO it's not such a clean practise if you have to do it everywhere in the codebase. I was wondering if there was a built-in way.. Guess not.. Thanks!